# Can Aminatou, the Fateshifter target herself with her -1 ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Aminatou, the Fateshifter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAminatou%2c%20the%20Fateshifter%5d) target herself with her -1 ability?

If this is the case, does it mean that she can create an infinite loop of "ETB" by herself?

Answer (score 11):

[Aminatou, the Fateshifter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAminatou%2c%20the%20Fateshifter%5d) cannot target herself with her -1 ability, because her ability says "another target permanent", which means she can target any permanent you own except for herself.

> −1: Exile **another target permanent** you own, then return it to the battlefield under your control.

Comment: Of course, if you have Nicol Bolas, Dragon God, or Spark Double, you can create a loop by having each planeswalker bounce the other one.  Of course, this won't be an infinite loop, [merely an arbitrarily large one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/does-going-infinite-necessarily-end-the-game?rq=1), and it doesn't do anything without something that triggers on planeswalkers entering or leaving the battlefield, but it does work.    Saheeli Rai and Felidar Gaurdian were used for a similar loop (until it got banned for being too powerful in Standard)